# Karma throwing unspecified RxJS/Subscriber.js error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, karma-runner, rxjs, subscribe

I'm using Karma with PhantomJS to run tests on components that are using RxJS.

The tests themselves seem to be doing fine but I keep getting this error at seemingly random times:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR

at webpack:///~/rxjs/Subscriber.js:194:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:608
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR

at webpack:///~/rxjs/Subscriber.js:194:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:608

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 100% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : 100% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : 100% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : 100% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================
```

The untranspiled Subscriber.ts:

```
error(err ? : any): void {
  if (!this.isStopped) {
    const {
      _parentSubscriber
    } = this;
    if (this._error) {
      ...
    } else if (!_parentSubscriber.syncErrorThrowable) {
      this.unsubscribe();
      throw err;
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Logging **err**, **_parentSubscriber.syncErrorThrowable** and **_parentSubscriber.syncErrorThrown** shows them as null, empty or undefined leading me to think there is no real error?

It almost seems like a logical issue rather than an actual problem, 'throw error when there is no error'? Inverting the else if-condition lets the tests run as normal, without any apparent problems.

What am I missing here?